# convolution integral involving modified Bessel functions of the first kind

Tags: integration, convolution, bessel-functions

I'm stuck with this convolution integral... 
\begin{equation}
f_{Z}(z)=\int^{\infty}_{0}f_{1}(x)f_{2}(z-x)dx = \mbox{ } ???
\end{equation}
which represents the pdf of the sum $Z = X_1 + X_2$ of two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$. Each $X_1$ and $X_2$ belongs to the same family (each of them is proportional to a [non-central $\chi^2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) variable):
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f_{1}(x) &= \alpha_1 e^{-\beta_1 x} (\gamma_1 x)^{\frac{1}{2} \nu} I_{\nu}(\delta_1 \sqrt{x}) \\
f_{2}(x) &= \alpha_2 e^{-\beta_2 x} (\gamma_2 x)^{\frac{1}{2} \mu} I_{\mu}(\delta_2 \sqrt{x}) 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $I_{\nu}(\cdot)$ and $I_{\mu}(\cdot)$ are modified [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) of the first kind of orders $\nu \geq 0$ and $\mu \geq 0$, respectively. Moreover, coefficients are all nonnegative: $a_i \geq 0, \beta_i \geq 0, \gamma_i \geq 0, \delta_i \geq 0$ and the

My questions:

1) can anybody provide a closed-form expression for the integral? Off course I know I can easily use Fourier, but I'm really wondering whether such pdf can be explicitly write down.

2) Moreover, is it possible to write $f_{Z}(z)$ as $f_1$ and $f_2$, i.e. do (?) $\left\{\alpha_z, \beta_z, \gamma_z, \delta_z, q \right\}$ exist such that
\begin{equation}
f_{Z}(z) = \alpha_z e^{-\beta_z z} (\gamma_z z)^{\frac{1}{2} q} I_{q}(\delta_z \sqrt{z})
\end{equation}

3) I'm separately interested in the case: $\nu = \mu = 0$.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Hint: If both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the sum of certain normal variables, so does $X_1+X_2$.

Comment: Thanks @JackD'Aurizio, but are you sure they really are? You would be perfectly right if $X_1$ and $X_2$ would have been exactly non-central $\chi^2$ distributed: if $X_i \sim \chi^2(k_i,\lambda_i)$ then $\sum_i X_i \sim \chi^2(\sum_i k_i, \sqrt{\sum_i \lambda^{2}_{i}})$ but they are only proportional to a non-central $\chi^2$ variable, and unfortunately, the non central $\chi^2$ distribution is not closed w.r.t. the scaling: $X \sim \chi^{2}(k,\lambda)$, then you CANNOT say that $\alpha X \sim \chi^2$. Indeed, what I'm asking in 2) is if -by chance- these pdf are closed w.r.t. convolution...